# 1,000 rows rendered to a table is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

Is there a way to update the screen faster? I am writing 1000 rows to a table, but it seems that electron, webkit or something cannot render fast enough. Once the data is told to write, it takes a few seconds for it to display on the screen.

I am not sure if it is my code or electron/node/webkit that is making it slow. Maybe it is jquery that is slow?

Here is what I am doing:

```
var tbody = $('#results-table-data>tbody');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var item = rows[i];
    var row = $('<tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
        var field = fields[j].name;
        var value = item[field] === null ? '(null)' : item[field];
        row.append('<td class="data-' + getTypeClass(columnTypes[j], item[field]) + '">' + value + '</td>');
    }
    tbody.append(row);
}
```

Comment: It may be jQuery. Try writing to tbody's `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Instead of adding the data as HTML, pass it to a plugin like [clusterize](https://clusterize.js.org/) and let it do the work.

Comment: @Mottie when I `require('./node_modules/clusterize.js/clusterize.js');` then do `new Clusterize(...)` I get `Clusterize is not defined` any thoughts on why?

Comment: It should look something like this: `require(['./node_modules/clusterize.js/clusterize.js'], function(Clusterize) { var clusterize = new Clusterize({ /* options */ }); });`

Comment: @Mottie I think that is for `requirejs` and not node's `require`

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop is not very efficient, but sometimes is necessary. One thing you can do to speed it up a little bit is to cache the lengths and array accessors:
It won't be a huge improvement for 1000 records, but it will help a bit.

```
 var tbody = $('#results-table-data>tbody');
for (var i = 0, rowsLength = rows.length; i < rowsLength; i++) {
    var item = rows[i];
    var row = $('<tr>');

    for (var j = 0, fieldsLength = fields.length; j < fieldsLength; j++) {
        var field = fields[j].name;
        var value = item[field] === null ? '(null)' : item[field];
        row.append('<td class="data-' + getTypeClass(columnTypes[j], item[field]) + '">' + value + '</td>');
    }
    tbody.append(row);
}
```

You can see a comparison of the loop times here:
https://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's normal, you are calling tbody.append() inside the for loop, do it just once (after everything is done and it will be a lot faster).

Just exit the tbody.append(row); from inside the foreach. You can add a new variable called rowsArray = []; and insert everything there.

An example with your code ( I cannot test it since we dont have all your code, but you get the idea ):

```
var tbody = $('#results-table-data>tbody');
var aRows = [];
var rowsLength = rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rowsLength; i++) {
    var item = rows[i];
    var row = $('<tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
        var field = fields[j].name;
        var value = item[field] === null ? '(null)' : item[field];
        row.append('<td class="data-' + getTypeClass(columnTypes[j], item[field]) + '">' + value + '</td>');
    }
    aRows.push(row);

    if( rowsLength == ( i+1 ) ){
        tbody.append( rowsLength );
    }
}
```

Comment: "you are asking the DOM to render each time a row is completed" I don't think that is accurate. The DOM will not be rendered and reflowed until the end of the JS event block.

Comment: It have the tbody.append(); in the for loop, so each time the loop passes and the new element is created, it append this element in the dom, that's why it will be a lot slower. But yes, you are right, it's not rendering everything again, it's just adding content to it. I updated my text, thanks ^_^

Comment: it is true that the append is in the loop but I claim that the DOM will not be rerendered by the browser until the JS event block is finished at which point there will be a single call to render the DOM. The browser is single threaded. It cannot rerender at the same time as running the JS.

Comment: @bhspencer [jQuery's learning site](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/) agrees with cedriking.  I'll see if I can't find a good explanation to mark as duplicate.  I know I've seen one.  Though you are right it wont' render, things are recalculated.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I don't doubt that touching the DOM comes at cost. I took issue with the claim that the cost is each touch of the DOM causing the browser to rerender the page which is false.

Comment: @bhspencer Fair enough, render is certainly not the right term there.

Comment: The word was eluding me, but it is "reflow" that is the issue, not rendering.